# Do I need to create a new taglib.xml file when migrating JSF 1.1 to JSF 2.0 while keeping JSP as view technology

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

Hi I have an application that needs to be migrated from jsf1.1 to jsf2.0. I have read the answers posted in [Migrating from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441713/migrating-from-jsf-1-2-to-jsf-2-0) by  BalusC.

I have thought not to go ahead converting JSP to facelets.Retain the JSP2.x as the view technology.

I would request someone to clarify couple of my doubts.

As a part of migrating the custom components is it a must to create a new custom-taglib.xml file ? Can't I retain .tld files as it is.

Since  JSF implementations like JSF 2.0 provides backward compatibility with older versions, Is it necessary to change the custom compoent code, for the deprecated methods and replace it with the appropriate methods from JSF 2.0? because we are not migrating it completely to facelets.

Answer (score 0):

> *Do I need to create a new taglib.xml file when migrating JSF 1.1 to JSF 2.0 while keeping JSP as view technology?*

No. The `*.taglib.xml` files are for Facelets what `*.tld` files are for JSP.